# How do I avoid cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null?

Tags: javascript, html

What can I do about this Error?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at HTMLButtonElement.SprawdzHaslo (index.html:56)

It shows up when I'm trying to show good or medium password first and then weak password `"HASŁO SŁABE"`.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("passwd");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var check = /[0-9]/;

function SprawdzHaslo() {
  if (x.value.length == 0 || x.value.length == "") {
    document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML = "<span style=color:red;> HASŁO PUSTE</span>";
  }

  if (x.value.length >= 4 && x.value.length <= 6 && x.value.match(check)) {
    document.getElementById("wynik1").innerHTML = "<span style=color:blue;> HASŁO ŚREDNIE</span>";
    
  } else if (x.value.length >= 7 && x.value.match(check)) {
    document.getElementById("wynik2").innerHTML = "<span style=color:green;> HASŁO DOBRE</span>";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("wynik3").innerHTML = "<span style=color:yellow;> HASŁO SŁABE</span>";
  }
}

button.onclick = SprawdzHaslo;
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="passwd" />
  <button type="button" id="button">Weryfikuj</button>
</form>

<div id="wynik" />
<div id="wynik1" />
<div id="wynik2" />
<div id="wynik3" />
```

Comment: You must close your `<div>`s: `<div id="wynik"></div>`

Comment: Try below code by changing button's onclick event calling method.    <buttons type="button" id="button" onClick="SprawdzHaslo()">Weryfikuj</button>

Comment: Understanding and using valid HTML is extremely important.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the JavaScript but with your HTML. Contrary to some elements like `img`, or `input` ([check the full list here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements)), `div` elements are not self-closing, meaning you must provide an end tag to them: `<div ...>...</div>`.

The way your HTML is parsed makes some of your divs get nested in each other (thanks @squint), hence the code working in some cases and not in others.

Comment: The divs don't actually disappear when parsed, but are created as nested divs, like `<div id="wynik"><div id="wynik1"><div id="wynik2"><div id="wynik3"></div></div></div></div>`. The parser sees that the closing tags are missing, but keeps the structure that was created as the opening tags were encountered (having ignored the invalid `/`).

Comment: The error is because the `.innerHTML` wipes out the nested content, and because the first `if` statement is followed by another `if` instead of an `else if`, the final `else` runs and looks for the div that has now been overwritten.